# How to create a SharePoint Team site which is connected to the Microsoft 365 groups using SharePoint Online Management Shell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, teamsite

If trying to create SharePoint Team site using PowerShell it will create the modern team site without connecting to the Microsoft 365 groups. I tried with template "STS#3".

I need to create modern team site which is connected with Microsoft 365 groups using SharePoint Online Management Shell.
To resolve this issue, give me any suggestions...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please use following PowerShell to create a team site which is connected to the Microsoft 365 group.

```
Connect-PnPOnline "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/"
$teamSiteUrl = New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title "Test" -Alias "test" -Description "test" -IsPublic
```

Comment: I'm checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If you find any answer is helpful to you, please remember to accept it.